# How to crop 4:5 using the Photos app

Tags: iphone, photos, ios, instagram, crop

After the latest updates (iOS 13), I can't find a native to crop a vertical image to `4:5` — I need that to upload photos on Instagram.

What's the alternative?

Comment: So are you looking for [software recommendations](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation)?

Comment: @ankii Preferably using the native tools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the crop tool in the Photos app, and then tap the crop presets button at the top right (looks like solid rectangle in another rectangle), you get some presets: Original, Freeform, Square, 9:16, 8:10, 5:7, etc.

But you want 4:5?

Just use 8:10. 4:5 = 8:10, right?